infer function params inside object
I am creating an object as below:
type AllLiterals = "one" | "two" | "three";

type ObjectConfig<T=unknown> = {
  path: string;
  value: AllLiterals;
  createPath?: (params:T)=>string
}

const config: Record<AllLiterals,ObjectConfig> = {
  one: {
    path: "one-path",
    value: "one",
  },
  two: {
    path: "two-path",
    value: "two",
    createPath: (a:string)=>`two-path/${a}`
  },
  three: {
    path: "three-path",
    value: "three",
    createPath: ({a, b}:{a:string,b:string})=>`three-path/${a}/${b}`
  }
}

when I try to use createPath, typescript cannot infer the type of params correctly, how can I solve this issue?
Also I need when I define createPath in each property of config, typescript knows that is does exist, and I do not need to check if createPath exists, then be able to use it.

how you suppose to infer using unknown?

• You have typos, why are you serializing params and what is a and b? Presumably you should be using params.a and params.b in there. Please [edit] to fix those. • You cannot infer type arguments this way. Your properties are not ObjectConfigs because unknown is wrong. To get inference of T you need to use a function call (otherwise you need to manually write out your types). See this playground link for an example for how to do it. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thanks for your answer, yes, that addresses my question. I will be glad if you create an answer from this comment. but I have another question, how can we fix this issue: if we use createPath without checking its existence we get this error:
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

I mean how can we create the config, that typescript knows for sure if createPath exists in a specific child object of config?

"but I have another question" Asking/answering a followup question in a comment isn't feasible.  Either your question above is fully addressed in which case I should write an answer for it, and you should post your next question as a new post so it can be answered...  or it's not fully addressed and this undefined thing is a requirement, in which case you should [edit] to note that, and then we can try to meet that requirement (e.g., like maybe in this playground link?) How would you like to proceed here?

@jcalz: Thanks for your help, the second one solves all of my issues.

You have to define the generic type, the keys in params will be the keys in genericType, you don't need all the keys because in the functions you are passing the specific type directly like params: { a: string } so TypeScript doesn't require the parameters in createPath to match all the properties of the genericType type.
type AllLiterals = "one" | "two" | "three";

type ObjectConfig<T=unknown> = {
     path: string;
  value: AllLiterals;
  createPath?: (params:T)=>string
}

interface GenericType {
  a: string; 
  b: string; 
  c: string; 
}
 
 

const config: Record<AllLiterals,ObjectConfig<GenericType>> = {
  one: {
    path: "one-path",
    value: "one",
  },
  two: {
    path: "two-path",
    value: "two",
    createPath: (params:{a:string })=>`two-path/${params.a}`
  },
  three: {
    path: "three-path",
    value: "three",
    createPath: (params:{ a: string; b: string })=>`three-path/${params.a}/${params.b}`
  }
}

If you want to have a union type for genericType containing multiple types, you need to change the type declaration for createPath to be genericType itself so that it requires all the properties from genericType.
The problem is that the union type won't know which one to match, so you have to use in to check the properties in the object before doing something
type AllLiterals = "one" | "two" | "three";

type ObjectConfig<T = unknown> = {
  path: string;
  value: AllLiterals;
  createPath?: (params: T) => string;
};

type GenericType = { a: string; b: string } | { a: string };

const config: Record<AllLiterals, ObjectConfig<GenericType>> = {
  one: {
    path: "one-path",
    value: "one",
  },
  two: {
    path: "two-path",
    value: "two",
    createPath: (params: GenericType) => `two-path/${params.a}`, 
  },
  three: {
    path: "three-path",
    value: "three",
    createPath: (params: GenericType) => {
      if ('b' in params) {
        return `three-path/${params.a}/${params.b}`;
      }
      return `three-path/${params.a}`;
    },
  },
};


Thanks fot the help, but the first approach clearly does not work, typescript will complain that we need all of the params to be passed to the createPath. Regarding the second, we may have lots of different params, and our AllLiterals is not just three, it will be at least 20, so this approach does not seem to be a good one too, cuz we need to define all the params beforehand. and then check each one in the createPath.
